# Stop warning box when attachment is still open in outlook 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, attachments

Stupid warning box keeps coming up when I close email and still have attachment open.

Comment: Remind me to look at this question tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't stop Outlook showing it you could easily setup [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to immediately close that dialog when it's shown.

You would put something like this at the top of your default AutoHotkey script:

```
; Example #1: Close unwanted windows whenever they appear:
#Persistent
SetTimer, CloseUnwantedWindows, 500
return

CloseUnwantedWindows:
SetTitleMatchMode 2

IfWinExist, Window Title you want to close, some text contents of window you want to close
{    
    WinClose
}
return
```

Once you set it up you'll eventually have tens of dialogs and windows you want to have close immediately and so it will pay for the initial hassle of setting up AutoHotkey.